# How to detect if a Tap or Tap Hold occurs while scrolling in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, touch-event

Is there any way in jQuery Mobile to detect whether a Tap or Tap Hold is occurring during a scroll event?  I keep getting phantom taps because I am scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $(document).on("taphold","selector",function(event){
        //do something you want on taphold event
    });
    $(document).on("tap","selector",function(event){
       //do something you want on tap event
    });
```

**selector** may be id/class selector of the element you want to handle tap/taphold event.